# Drop Down Menu Tracking in Google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

Snippet

[image]

DropDown Menu

[image]

I am trying too track the selected option of attached dropdown menu, tried to do it according to Simo Ahava's guidelines but not able to track it. the listener selectionMade is not visible in preview mode of GTM. Kindly look for possible error and suggest a way to track.

Comment: You've added the same picture twice. Also, please don't post pictures of code or other text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.